# Initialization of 2D Array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java-2d

I've a little confusion, when we declare & initialize a 2D array in java like given below

```
int arr[][]={{1,2,3,4},{4,3,2,1}};
```

This work correct, but when do do the above action like given below

```
int arr[2][4]={{1,2,3,4},{4,3,2,1}};
```

Then why it generates an error? Why can't we fix the size of rows and columns and then assign values in same statement? I know that we can do that separately using loops, something like `arr[0][0]=345;` and so on, but why can't we do it like this?

```
int arr[4][2]={{1,2,3,4},{4,3,2,1}};
```

Comment: You can't do it, because that is simply not how Java is designed. Asking why that is, is asking for opinions, which is off-topic. As an aside, although putting array brackets on the variable name is possible in Java, the recommended way is to put them on the type, so `int[][] arr` instead of `int arr[][]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s because Java is not C language.
When you write `int arr[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};`, you declare and initialize a multidimensional array of 2 by 4. It is equivalent to the C language initialization you proposed (`int arr[2][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};`)

In Java, we preferably declare arrays in a Java-style manner:

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};
```

where `int[][]` is just a type identifier, we cannot specify size.
Moreover, in Java, we can initialize a 2D array that is not rectangular:

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3}};
```

If you want to declare an array of specific size, but don’t want to specify all it’s values at once, the only solution is to use `new`:

```java
int[][] arr = new int[2][4];
arr[0][0] = 1;
```